# SQLITE Query forces application close

Tags: android, sqlite

I have checked everything and the creating of the database is fine its when I try to add data to it that it forces the app to close. I cant see why.

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME2    
            + " (GenID INT, "
            + " Nxtq INT);");

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME2 +
            " Values (1,1);");
```

The error I get output is

> Failure 1 (table general has 4 columns but 2 values were supplied) when prepearing  'INSERT INTO general values (1,1)

There is some stuff before these two query's here it is in its entirety.

```
    db =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
            " (ID INT(3), Questions VARCHAR, Answer1 VARCHAR," +
            " Answer2 VARCHAR, Answer3 VARCHAR," +
            " Answer4 VARCHAR, CorrectAnswer INT(1), Reason VARCHAR);");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME2    
            + " (GenID INT, "
            + " Nxtq INT);");

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME2 +
            " Values (1,1);");
```

Comment: Which statement is it failing on? Can you add debug statements to help pinpoint?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @p.campbell @Damp Its something to do with the number of columns. The error reads Failure 1 (table general has 4 columns but 2 values were supplied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing the name of "general" to something else like "general_new" and see if the script works, as mentioned, general the table might already exist (even if you don't think you made it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your exception. Do that before posting here, and include the relevant bits of LogCat output if you do not understand them.

In this case, I suspect that you will find that `INT(3)` is not [a valid SQLite datatype](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html), but that is just a guess.

Comment: Can you possibly provide a good tutorial or anything on using Eclipse to examine what I need to. It may be of more use in the long run.

Comment: @Max: Well, there is some documentation on these tools on the developer.android.com Web site in the Dev Guide tab. I don't have any ready links to public Eclipse-and-Android-specific tutorials, but I would imagine you can find some with a Google search. Of course, there are lots of books on Android development, many of which go into the use of these tools, some of which I wrote... :-)

Comment: Its something to do with the number of columns. The error reads
Failure 1 (table general has 4 columns but 2 values were supplied)

Answer (score 0):

@Max
for the insert try using db.insert(........);

Comment: why should I use this? What is the difference. At the moment all my insert querys are run the same way as this and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The table in question - named `general` - already exists before the above code is executed.  This prior-existing table has four columns, hence the `INSERT INTO` with two columns fails.  The `CREATE TABLE` does nothing because `IF NOT EXISTS` is false.

You mention that the database is created correctly - does your application start with an empty database, or might it re-use an existing one?  Alternatively, perhaps there is some code that is called earlier that creates a table named `general` with a 4-column scheme.  This clashes with the above.

Comment: The entire database part of the script is what I have posted with an extra part on the front that creates another table called friends. That table I have had running fine and can insert and retrieve data from no problem. Its now that I've tried to create a second table like I would in PHP. I have added this above

Comment: try changing the name of "general" to something else like "general_new" and see if the script works, as mentioned, general the table might already exist (even if you don't think you made it yourself).

Comment: @Max - You're using openOrCreateDatabase directly, I'm not sure that's recommended. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: I changed it from general to general_q and it worked. Is there some reserved status for general? Thanks for the heads up @martin clayton I will take a look into it

Comment: @Seph If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it as thats what I did to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

What's the respective values of `SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME` and `SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME2`? Is it possible that they are equal like so:

```
private static final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "general";
private static final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME2 = "general";
```